# Random crashes on XFCE - how to diagnose what's happening?

Tags: linux, freeze, x-server

I'm on Parabola (a fork of Arch), and I'm running the XFCE desktop environment. However, I periodically get these weird crashes, where my entire desktop freezes. I have no ability to move my cursor (in fact, I can't even *see* my cursor), my machine doesn't respond to *any* keyboard input (I can't even switch to another tty), and basically only the power button works. However, at the same time, if I (for example) have music playing in the background, then it keeps playing without problems.

I'm totally unsure how to diagnose the source of my problem. Where can I look, and what would I be looking for to detect what causes such behaviour?

Comment: This may actually be a problem of/with X, not specific to XCFE.

Comment: @Ned64 I'm not sure what the problem is with - my question was 'How can I diagnose its source?' more than 'How do I fix this?'

Comment: OK. First off, I would check out `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and your own log, called something like `~/.xsession-errors` (see `ls -trdl ~/.??*` to find relevant files (new files at the bottom)).  You need to copy the data from these files before starting X the second time i case they are overwritten (but also see `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` for possibly the previous version.).

Comment: @Ned64 What am I looking for in such a case? Neither of the Xorg logs seem to contain anything unusual, but the .xsession-errors ones have a lot of possible issues.

Comment: Wow, that's difficult, I am not an expert on X!  It may help to have the logs of one session with problems, and another without.  Comparing the logs may yield information.  At that stage (or now) it may be useful to file a bug report with the maintainers of Xorg or XFCE (I would tend to "blame" Xorg, as nothing a window manager does should really crash Xorg).

Comment: PS: You could logging into your machine via SSH, or at least pinging it (e.g. via Android app LanDroid) to see how down your machine is when has a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your music keeps playing for more than a few seconds, that means the system is running fine, except that the X server is so frozen that it doesn't respond to any console input. Switching between ttys requires the cooperation of the X server, both to handle the key combination and to reset the graphics card.

If you have another way to log into the machine, you can run commands and attempt to debug the problem or at least perform a clean shutdown. For most people, a way to log into the machine would be SSH from another computer (which could be a smartphone — there are terminal emulators and SSH clients for the major smartphone operating systems).

From a command line, you can try running `chvt 1` as root to switch to a different text console. That may or may not work though, depending on what the X server is doing. If the X server is not responding, the switch may fail, or you may end up typing blind because the text console graphics mode was not set up correctly.

Another thing that can be useful is the [magic SysRq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key): press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press <kbd>SysRq</kbd> (you can release it), press a letter mnemonic, and release all keys. This is handled directly by the kernel, so it'll keep working as long as the kernel isn't completely locked up. If you don't have SSH access, try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to switch the keyboard out of raw mode, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a text console. When the keyboard is no longer in raw mode, the key binding is handled directly by the kernel, so this has a chance of working. Like running `chvt`, the actual VT switch may be impaired by the X server.

If you manage to get a command line, here are some things you can look at as a first level of investigation:

- Run `htop` or `top` and see what processes are keeping the CPU busy.
- Check for messages in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, `/var/log/kern.log` (or wherever your distribution keeps kernel logs) or `~/.xsession-errors` (or wherever your session managers directs stdout and stderr).

If some X process is taking 100% CPU time or sharing with the X server, try killing it. Compiz is a frequent offender.

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to kill the X server and all the processes in the X session. This, too, will leave the graphics card in a bad state. You can then try running a new X server. There's a good chance that it will be able to reinitialize the graphics card.

Common problems that cause lockups are:

- A buggy 3D graphics driver. 3D drivers are a lot buggier than 2D (this is understandable since they're newer, more complex, and even more poorly supported by hardware manufacturers). Try relying less on 3D stuff. In particular, avoid compiz.
- A buggy graphics driver. If you're using the free driver for your GPU, try the proprietary one, or vice versa. Try a more recent or older version.
- Bad RAM. Run a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/).

Comment: Wow, thank you! This is *very* comprehensive. Does XFCE use Compiz by default? I don't remember installing it or setting it up.

Comment: XFCE does not use Compiz by default, you can edit the setting "Compositing Window Manager" somewhere.

Comment: @Gilles I've tried *every* possible SysRq option listed on that Wikipedia page - none of them respond. I *can* ping the machine successfully, though. I haven't tried SSH yet.